# Restrictions on the coefficients that allow a polynomial in a field of characteristic 0 to be solvable by radicals and the associated formula.

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots

Given a field $F$ of characteristic $0$, we know that a general polynomial $p(x) \in F \left[ x \right]$ is *not* solvable by radicals if $n \geq 5$. However, I was wondering what restrictions can one place on the coefficients of $p(x)$ to get it to be solvable.

For example, suppose 
$$ p(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 $$
where $a_i = a_0^i$.

With the above restriction on the coefficients (for example), can one get relatively simple formulas for the roots or at least prove the associated Galois group is not solvable?

**Edit/Clarification.** The way I am thinking about this problem is by analogy with how one proves the general polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $F$ is not solvable by radicals for $n \geq 5$. This is done using the following theorem due to Galois

***Theorem:*** Let $F$ be a field. Then $p(x) \in F \left[ x \right]$ is solvable if and only if the Galois group of $p(x)$ is a solvable group.

Once one has this correspondence, we show that the Galois group of a polynomial in $F[x]$ with degree $n \geq 5$ is $S_n$. This is achieved by recognizing that the Galois group of $t^n + a_1 t^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n$ over $F(a_1, \cdots , a_n)$, the field of rational functions in $n$ variables, is $S_n$. (We of course can always make a polynomial monic with out changing the solvability.) However $S_n$ is not a solvable group for $n \geq 5$. Hence, such polynomials cannot be solvable by radicals.

However, *the proofs of the various lemmas and theorems that eventually produce the above theorem assume that the coefficients are arbitrary*. So my question is

> Are there special restrictions one can put on the coefficients that make the polynomial solvable? More explicitly, when we restrict ourselves from an arbitrary polynomial in $F[x]$ to a polynomial that has coefficients which are related to one another in some simple way (e.g. $a_i = a_0^i$), how does the Galois group change? In particular, is the Galois group of this new polynomial some solvable subgroup of $S_n$?. Moreover, can we find the associated formula for the roots with ease? (For the case of $a_i = a_0^i$, I imagine the formula for the roots is some relatively 'simple' function of $a_0$)

Comment: Note that replacing $x$ by $x/a_0$ reduces this to $x^n+x^{n-1}+\dots + x + a_0$. So the problem is reduced to whether or not this is soluble by radicals.

Comment: An irreducible polynomial equation is solvable iff its Galois group is solvable — if this doesn't answer you question, what is you question exactly?

Comment: @MikeMiller I had realized this shortly after I post it, but that only applies to this example. I am also looking for other possible structure of the coefficients that allowed solvability.

Comment: You should be explicit about what other possible structure there can be on the coefficients.

Comment: @GrigoryM Yes I am aware of this. The fact that you stated about the Galois Group is a way one can prove the insolvability of the general polynomial of degree $n$ (where the coefficients are assumed to be entirely arbitrary). Once one has this criteria, it is easy to show that the Galois group of the polynomial for $n \geq 5$ contains $S_5$ which is not a solvable group. This is achieved by recognizing that the galois group of $t^n + a_1 t^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n$ over $F(a_1, \cdots , a_n)$ (the field of rational functions in $n$ variables) is $S_n$. I will edit the post and include more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case in which $f(x)$ is an irreducible quintic with rational coefficients.

A well-known paper by D.S. Dummit, [Solving Solvable Quintics](http://www.emba.uvm.edu/~ddummit/quintics/solvable.pdf), approaches the problem by constructing a *sixth* degree rational polynomial $g(x)$ from the coefficients of $f(x)$.  The result is that $f(x)$ is solvable if and only if $g(x)$ has a rational root.  The [Rational Root Thm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) then gives us a way to test for rational roots of $g(x)$.

In particular any quintic is easily transformed into an equivalent *depressed monic quintic*, with a leading coefficient 1 and zero coefficient of $x^4$.  Dummit then gives the explicit sixth degree polynomial $g(x)$ that corresponds to this depressed quintic $f(x)$.

Once a rational root of $g(x)$ is found, Dummit gives formulas that allow us to express the roots of $f(x)$ "analogous to Cardano’s formulas for the general cubic and quartic
polynomials".